# Can I force expand android notification on android 4.1+?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I wonder if I could force expand my notification which have 2 buttons, because I don't think users will find them if they are not expanded.

Poweramp seems achieved that, anyone please help me. thx in advance.

[image]

Comment: Off topic???  Really.  Seems like a perfectly valid question with an example of exactly what they are looking for.   On top of that the accepted answer is perfect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I know, the first notification in the notification tray is always presented with the expanded view by default (if a BigView is defined for the notification).

So, what you could do is increase the priority of your notification so that it becomes the first notification in the tray, and that way, it will always be expanded by default.

**`mNotification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;`**