# Android show notification only when the status bar is expanded

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

Is it possible in Android to show notification only when the status bar is expanded? I mean only when I dragged down the status bar, I can see the notification otherwise it will be hidden. If it is possible how I can implement it? I just need to hide the application icon from status bar when it is in the minimal view.[Check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6w0z.png)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798565/can-i-force-expand-android-notification-on-android-4-1

Comment: @Kelevandos, I don't need to display the notification in expanded view forced. I want to remove the icon from the status bar when it not expanded.

Comment: Then please edit your question to reflect that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I figured it out myself that from Android 4.1 (API 16) it's possible to specify a notification's priority. If you set that flag to PRIORITY_MIN the notification icon won't show up on the statusbar but you are still able to view the notification on expanding the statusbar.

```
// Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setOngoing(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("my_title"); 
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(ic_launcher);
// Do other stuffs here.

 notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN);// Set this.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `builder.setSmallIcon(...)` to your `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder` which you are using.

Code you need to try to get small icon in notification:

```
   // Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   /* icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of
     notification */
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);//Set this
   .....
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to remove that icon from the status bar when the status bar is not expanded.